# How to create a tikz figure in a secondary .tex file and import it into a main .tex file?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made a figure with `TiKZ`, with a lot of lines of code. It is difficult to edit text with a large number of lines for the figure.

How could I create the figure in an individual file and import it into my main file?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    ....
    ....
    ....
\end{figure}
```

Regards,
Max.

Comment: Why not create the figure with the `standalone` class, and include  the resulting .pdf via `\includegraphics{my_tikz_picture}`?

Comment: Using the multi or tikz options, you can put each image on a separate page of one PDF and use `\includegraphics[page=...]{my_tikz_pictures}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put tikz code into separate `.tex` file and then `\input` that in main file.

For example, `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
This is my picture:
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \input mypicture.tex
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and inputing `mypicture.tex`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,fill=blue!30,rounded corners,font=\Large]
        {Hello, world!};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

get following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just what i was looking for.